# Inserting hyphen or en dash in a string vector depending on location of specific elements

Tags: regex, r, string, vector, gsub

Given is a [string](/questions/tagged/string) [vector](/questions/tagged/vector) `vecA`:

```
vecA <- c("Population 1222",
          "Population 90over",
          "population under78",
          "population 99101",
          "Population 1254", 
          "Population 78 92")
```

## Problem

I would like to arrive at the `vecB` that would correspond to:

```
vecB <- c("Population 12 - 22",
          "Population 90 over",
          "population under 78",
          "population 99 - 101",
          "Population 12 - 54", 
          "Population 78 - 92")
```

### Key characteristics

The `vecB` has the following characteristics:

- After the first two digits space and dash and space are inserted (`-`)
- If the space exists only the dash (`-`) is inserted
- For combinations like **`underDigitDigit`** only space is inserted: **`under DigitDigit`**

---

## Attempts

I was thinking of making use of groups in [gsub](/questions/tagged/gsub), on the lines:

```
gsub("^([[:alpha:]]*[[:blank:]])(\\d{2})(.*)$", "\\2", vecA)
```

but that does not work for all the cases:

```
> t(t(gsub("^([[:alpha:]]*[[:blank:]])(\\d{2})(.*)$", "\\2", vecA)))
     [,1]                
[1,] "12"                
[2,] "90"                
[3,] "population under78"
[4,] "99"                
[5,] "12"                
[6,] "78"
```

*`t()` applied for the presentational purposes only; [regex101 link](https://regex101.com/r/dN2oS9/1).*

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is my suggestion - do it in two steps: 1) add the hyphen between the numbers first, and then 2) add the space between words "over"/"under" and the number:

```
vecA <- c("Population 1222",
           "Population 90over",
           "population under78",
           "population 99101",
           "Population 1254", 
           "Population 78 92")
v <- gsub("^([[:alpha:]]+[[:blank:]]+)([[:digit:]]{2})\\s*([[:digit:]])", "\\1\\2 - \\3", vecA)
gsub("^([[:alpha:]]+[[:blank:]]+)(?|(over|under)(\\d+)|(\\d+)(over|under))", "\\1\\2 \\3", v, perl=T)
```

Output of a [code demo](https://ideone.com/n4yXVp):

```
[1] "Population 12 - 22"  "Population 90 over"  "population under 78"
[4] "population 99 - 101" "Population 12 - 54"  "Population 78 - 92"
```

The second regex contains a branch reset pattern `(?|...|...)` to keep the same group IDs in the alternative subpatterns, thus requires a `perl=T`.